# is Express initialized first in Node initialization dependencies?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm having a **problem during the initialization** of a system. In order to initialize this system, I'm calling the **index.ts** file. This file imports an initializer **class** called **StartServer**. This class has an *async* method called **start** that initialize all the system database connections and express server. **The problem is**, *somehow* Node initialize express files, **index.routes.ts**, where the routes are defined, and all it dependencies, **before** starting the index file with the initializer class, generating an error of undefined due to no connections exits at this point.

**index.ts file :**

```
import { StartServer } from './services';

StartServer.start();
```

**StarterServer.ts file :**

```
export class StartServer {
  public static async start(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const configPort: IConfig = config.get('App.port');

      await Connections.startDatabaseConnections();

      const server = ServerFactory.create();
      await server.init();

      console.log(`Server is listening at port ${configPort}...`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error((error as Error)?.stack);
    }
  }
}
```

**ExpressServer.ts file :**

```
import routes from '../routes/index.routes';

export class ExpressApp {
  private app = express();
  private port = config.get('App.port');

  routes() {
    this.app.use(routes);
  }

  async init() {
    this.routes();
    this.app.listen(this.port);
  }
}
```

**index.routes.ts file :**

```
import express from 'express';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (_, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'App listening...' });
});

export default router;
```

**ServerFactory.ts file :**

```
import { ExpressApp } from '@src/services';

export class ServerFactory {
  public static create() {
    return new ExpressApp();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Node, `import` (and `require`) are synchronous. As soon as you require a file it is executed.

```js
// a.js
import b from './b';
console.log('a.js');

//b.js
import c from './c';
console.log('b.js');

// c.js
console.log('c.js');
```

That will output:

```
c.js
b.js
a.js
```

In your case, the `index.routes.ts` will be executed as soon as it's required by `ExpressServer.ts`. One pattern to avoid initialisation is to export a factory function to perform the setup. You're doing this for your server already!

```js
import express from 'express';

export default function createRouter() {
    const router = express.Router();

    router.get('/', (_, res) => {
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'App listening...' });
    });
}
```

Comment: thx so much for your help!!! =D, it worked beautifully